# Decoding many different resources continuously in Android

Tags: android

I am currently working on a game for Android. The game is a real time strategy game that uses tiles or cells and has actors (units, trees, rock, etc.) that will occupy those cells.

In my game, cells and actors are objects that have their own draw method. For fear of speed problems, I currently decode the resource in the map class and feed the decoded image to the object's draw method.

Like this:

```
_waterCell = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.watertile);
...
_row.get(Cell).draw(_waterCell, canvas, _paint, _X, _Y);
```

This is fine for now, considering I have few cell types and only one actor but how would I go about this when I have hundreds of images to decode without having to decode the resource every time I draw the object? And if I were to decode all of my resources in the map class, would it cause out of memory errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say whether decoding the resources would cause an out of memory error since I don't know their size. However, the decoding of the resource itself, assuming there is enough memory to handle whatever is being decoded should not cause an out of memory exception. The more likley result is, depending on how frequently you need to decode resources, it will just slow your app down.

Have you considered using a cache? If you're decoding resources you could use a simple `LRUcache` [as demonstrated in the android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) to avoid repeating this process. If you decode your resources as needed, store them to the cache, and then check the cache fore their presence before decoding again - you can probably save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks, this is really informative. I wasn't aware of this functionality